# Double Orthogonal Complements in a Bilinear Form with a Specific Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, vector-spaces, bilinear-form

I'm studying a problem from linear algebra:

For a bilinear form $b: V \times V$ and a subvector space $U $ in $ V $ we set
$ U^{\perp}:=\{v \in V \mid b(u, v)=0 \text { for all } u \in U\} . $
Now let $ A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & -1 \\ -1 & 1\end{array}\right)$. We consider the bilinear form
$ b: \mathbb{R}^{2} \times \mathbb{R}^{2} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}, \quad(x, y) \mapsto x^{t} A y $
Prove or disprove (by giving a counterexample): For every $ \mathbb{R} $ subvector space $U $ in $ \mathbb{R}^{2}$ we have $ \left(U^{\perp}\right )^{\perp}=U$.

This should be correct because we just deal with finite dimensional vector spaces.

Here is my proof:

Let $ u \in U $ with $\langle u, w\rangle =0 \quad \forall w \in U^{\perp},$ so $ u \in U^{\perp \perp} $.

Consequently $ U \subseteq U^{\perp \perp} $.

Since we know that V is the direct sum of $U$ and  $U^{\perp}$:
$\operatorname{dim}(U) = \operatorname{dim}(V)-\operatorname{dim}\left(U^{\perp}\right) =\operatorname{dim}(V)-\left(\operatorname{dim}(V)-\operatorname{dim}\left(U^{\perp \perp}\right)\right)=\operatorname{dim} \left(U^{\perp \perp}\right),$
it follows $U=U^{\perp \perp}$.

Comment: Your assumption that $V$ is a direct sum of $U$ and $U^\perp$ is not true for every $U$. One hint I can give is that the matrix $A$ defining the form is singular. You might think about what happens for a subspace spanned by a vector in the kernel of $A$ (e.g. (1,1))

Comment: @SamBallas
Let $U = \text{span}(\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix})$
and by the definition of   $ U^{\perp}:=\{v \in V \mid b(u, v)=0 \text { for all } u \in U\}$ I think that  $ U^{\perp} =  \text{span}(\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix})$ and $\left(U^{\perp}\right )^{\perp} = \left(\text{span}(\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix})\right)^{\perp} = \text{span}(\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}) \neq U$

Comment: I found this problem referring to my question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/636517/is-it-true-that-the-whole-space-is-the-direct-sum-of-a-subspace-and-its-orthogon

But I want to use the example given in the task

Comment: Not quite. In this case $U^\perp=\mathbb{R}^2$, since it contains the vectors $(1,-1)$ AND $(1,1)$. In fact the vector $(1,1)$ is in the kernel of $A$ and so it is orthogonal to EVERY vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$, so whatever $(U^\perp)^\perp$ is it will contain $(1,1)$.

Comment: @SamBallas Right! Just posted my answer, let me know what you think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\qquad$*Disproof !*

The specific bilinear form you propose allows for the canonical counter-example
$\,U = \{0\}\,$ since the defining matrix $A$ is singular, which corresponds to the associated bilinear form being degenerate.
We clearly & always have
$\,U^\perp = \{0\}^\perp = V$,
but then & here
$$\left(U^{\perp}\right )^{\perp}\;=\; V^\perp\;=\;
\langle{1\choose 1}\rangle \;\neq\;\{0\}=U.$$
Going into more detail:
The defining matrix $A$ has the eigenvalues $\{0,2\}$
with respective (non-normalised) eigenvectors
${1\choose 1}$ and ${1\choose -1}\,$.
As a statement about diagonalisation of $A$
this may be written as
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 \\ -1 & 1\end{pmatrix}
\;\frac1{\sqrt 2}\begin{pmatrix}1& 1\\ 1& -1\end{pmatrix} 
 \;=\; \frac1{\sqrt 2}\begin{pmatrix}1& 1\\ 1& -1\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} 0& 0\\ 0& 2\end{pmatrix}$$

Regarding your proof attempt:
Your first conclusion $U\subseteq U^{\perp \perp}$ is true.

In case of degeneracy, $V$ is in general not the direct sum,
e.g., it does not fit for $U^{\perp}$ and $U^{\perp\perp}\,$.